# useContext returning undefined values

Tags: reactjs, use-context

Facing this problem where my context returns undefined values, all it is returning is the initial state. Here in the transaction list im trying to call the function deleteTransaction I defined, but its giving error that it is undefined. Please tell me if im missing something or need to add something.

These are my dependecies, just in case.

```
"dependencies": {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.10",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.6",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
},
```

GlobalState.js:

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from 'react'
import AppReducer from './AppReducer'

const initialState = {
transactions: [
    {id:1, text:"Flower", amount:-20},
    {id:2, text:"Salary", amount:300},
    {id:3, text:"Book", amount:-10},
    {id:4, text:"Camera", amount:150}
]
}

export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState)

export const GlobalProvider = (props) => {
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState)

const deleteTransaction = (id) => {
    dispatch({type:'DELETE_TRANSACTION', payload:id})
}

return (<GlobalContext.Provider value={{transactions:state.transactions, deleteTransaction}}>
    {props.children}
</GlobalContext.Provider>)
}
```

AppReducer.js:

```
export default (state, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case 'DELETE_TRANSACTION':
        return {
            ...state,
            transactions: state.transactions.filter(transaction => transaction.id !== action.payload)
        }
    default:
        return state
}
}
```

TransactionList.js:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState'
import { Transaction } from './Transaction'

export const TransactionList = () => {

const { transactions } = useContext(GlobalContext)

return (
    <>
        <h3>History</h3>
        <ul className="list">
            {transactions.map(transaction => (
                <Transaction key={transaction.id} {...transaction} />
            ))}
        </ul>
    </>
)
}
```

Transaction.js:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react'
import { GlobalContext } from '../context/GlobalState'

export const Transaction = ({id, text, amount}) => {

const {deleteTransaction} = useContext(GlobalContext)

const sign = amount < 0 ? "-" : "+"

return (
    <div>
        <li className={amount < 0 ? "minus" : "plus"}>
            {text} <span>{sign}${Math.abs(amount)}</span><button onClick={() => 
deleteTransaction(id)} className="delete-btn">x</button>
        </li>
    </div>
)
}
```

Comment: You need to wrap your component with `GlobalProvider` where you want to use the context

Comment: Is your GlobalProvider in the parent hierarchy of TransactionList Component

Comment: Such a silly mistake. Im not so experienced with React but idk how I forgot to wrap it up with my GlobalProvider. Thanks for you time. Its all working now.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Your default context value is missing the `deleteTransaction` function.

```
const initialState = {
  transactions: [
    {id:1, text:"Flower", amount:-20},
    {id:2, text:"Salary", amount:300},
    {id:3, text:"Book", amount:-10},
    {id:4, text:"Camera", amount:150}
  ]
}

export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState)
```

## Solution

Define your context's default value shape to match what is used by components and ensure that `Transaction` has a `GlobalContext.Provider` above it in the React tree.

```
const defaultValue = {
  transactions: [],
  deleteTransaction: () => {}, // <-- add a deleteTransaction function
}

export const GlobalContext = createContext(defaultValue);
```

[Updating Context from a Nested Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#updating-context-from-a-nested-component)

> It is often necessary to update the context from a component that is
> nested somewhere deeply in the component tree. In this case you can
> pass a function down through the context to allow consumers to update
> the context.
>
> **theme-context.js**
>
> ```
> // Make sure the shape of the default value passed to
> // createContext matches the shape that the consumers expect!
> export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
>   theme: themes.dark,
>   toggleTheme: () => {},
> });
> ```

Comment: This isn't the context's initialState, it is the value that is used, if there is no Provider in the hierarchy

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri OP called it initial state, I just initially used the same name they did, but you're correct, `createContext` takes a default value.